# How set timer for multiple parallel running Azure durable functions in python?

Tags: python, azure, asynchronous, azure-functions, azure-durable-functions

I try to start multiple parallel activity functions in a durable function, and wait for a predetermined time. After that time I don't care about the long running functions, I want to use only the return value of the finished ones. How can I achieve this?

```
def orchestrator_function(context: df.DurableOrchestrationContext):
    # set post-processors
    post_deadline = context.current_utc_datetime + timedelta(seconds=10)
    post_timeout_task = context.create_timer(post_deadline)
    
    post_processors = []
    post_processors.append(context.call_activity("StartStoredProcedure", (1, 'post-processor_1')))
    post_processors.append(context.call_activity("StartStoredProcedure", (30, 'post-processor_2')))
    post_processors.append(post_timeout_task)
    
    # run data-collectors parallel, and wait for completion
    postproc_results = yield context.task_all(post_processors)
```

The `task_all` will wait for the long running functions, and the `task_any` will stop at the first. I would like to wait 10 secs, and get the info from the finished functions, and release the others.
Any pattern idea?

Answer (score 0):

> After that time I don't care about the long running functions, I want to use only the return value of the finished ones. How can I achieve this?

I believe if your ask is need of using the return value of the finished ones, then ***Function Chaining application pattern*** in Azure Durable Functions is the good option.

In this pattern, the output of one function is applied to the input of another function.

**Here is the [Microsoft Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable/durable-functions-overview?tabs=csharp#chaining) about the above-suggested pattern information.**

> I would like to wait 10 secs, and get the info from the finished functions, and release the others. Any pattern idea?

There is a concept called Durable timers used in durable functions for implementing delays or setting up timeouts on async actions.
In Python, `time.sleep()` used as a durable timer in the durable functions.

**Please check [Timers in Azure Durable Functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable/durable-functions-timers?tabs=python) for more information.**

Comment: Unfortunately function chaining can't be a solution here, because that isn't a parallel run. I want run parallel let's say 100 functions, but these functions doesn't care about each other. And I want to aggregate the outputs of these parallel running functions, but forgetting the long running ones.
In the example above I used the .create_timer durable timer, but unfortunately we have only the task_all and task_any to wait for the parallel running processes. The timer is enough if you want to control only one activity function, but for controlling multiple ones I don't find an elegant pattern.

Comment: In the fan out/fan in pattern, you execute multiple functions in parallel and then wait for all functions to finish. Often, some aggregation work is done on the results that are returned from the functions.

Comment: Yes, the code above is that pattern. But that alone doesn't solve my problem. Of course you can set a max run time for the activity functions in the function.json, but that way you explicitly say that you want to stop the activity function after that time. But I don't want to stop the parallel activity functions, I just don't want to wait for their return value at that particular step.

Answer (score 0):

Im not very familiar with python for durable functions but with C# it could be achieved with a Task.WhenAll inside Task.WhenAny

```
    TimeSpan timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10);
    DateTime deadline = context.CurrentUtcDateTime.Add(timeout);

    using (var cts = new CancellationTokenSource())
    {
        List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>();
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            tasks.Add(context.CallActivityAsync("SomeFunc", someData));
        Task timeoutTask = context.CreateTimer(deadline, cts.Token);

        Task winner = await Task.WhenAny(activityTask, Task.WhenAll(tasks));
        List<ResultType> aggResult = new List<ResultType>;
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            if (tasks[i].Status == TaskStatus.RanToCompletion)
               aggResult.Add(tasks[i].Result)
    }
```

You might be able to do something similar with python

```
def orchestrator_function(context: df.DurableOrchestrationContext):
    # set post-processors
    post_deadline = context.current_utc_datetime + timedelta(seconds=10)
    post_timeout_task = context.create_timer(post_deadline)
    
    post_processors = []
    post_processors.append(context.call_activity("StartStoredProcedure", (1, 'post-processor_1')))
    post_processors.append(context.call_activity("StartStoredProcedure", (30, 'post-processor_2')))
    
    # run data-collectors parallel, and wait for completion
    finished_task = yield context.task_any([post_timeout_task, context.task_all(post_processors)])
    if finished_task != post_timeout_task:
       post_timeout_task.cancel()
#Loop over each task in post_processors to aggregate functions where Result != None
```

If this is not allowed in python i suppose a solution that is not very elegant but would work is

```
def orchestrator_function(context: df.DurableOrchestrationContext):
    # set post-processors
    post_deadline = context.current_utc_datetime + timedelta(seconds=10)
    post_timeout_task = context.create_timer(post_deadline)
    
    post_processors = []
    post_processors.append(context.call_activity("StartStoredProcedure", (1, 'post-processor_1')))
    post_processors.append(context.call_activity("StartStoredProcedure", (30, 'post-processor_2')))
    post_processors.append(post_timeout_task)
    results = []
    while len(post_processors) != 1: # Only timeout task exists
        finished_task = yield context.task_any(post_processors)
        post_processors = [x for x in post_processors if x != finished_task]
        if finnished_task == post_timeout_task:
           break
        results.append(finished_task.result)
     if post_processors[0] == post_timeout_task:
        post_timeout_task.cancel()
```

Comment: this seems to be a good solution, thanks Bjorne